# OutboundPathProcessor is not appending $options array?

Tags: 8, uri

I have a simple `OutboundPathProcessor` that should append a query string and a URL fragment, but nothing is happening.

#### mymodule.services.yml

```
services:
  mymodule.path_processor:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor\MyModulePathProcessor
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_outbound }
```

#### MyModulePathProcessor.php

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor;

use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\OutboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MyModulePathProcessor implements OutboundPathProcessorInterface {

  function processOutbound($path, &$options = array(), Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {

    $options['query']['foo'] = 'bar';
    $options['fragment'] = 'baz';

    return $path;
  }

}
```

It seems the `$options` array is passed by reference, and in fact [LanguageNegotiationUrl::processOutbound](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!language!src!Plugin!LanguageNegotiation!LanguageNegotiationUrl.php/function/LanguageNegotiationUrl%3A%3AprocessOutbound/8.2.x) is placing multiple values in the `$options` array.

Why doesn't my code work?

I just figured out that it does work if I add a URL prefix using `$options['prefix'] = 'prefix/';`, so some options are getting applied.
Why aren't fragment and query used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a [bug report](https://www.drupal.org/node/2507005) for that. I found a reference to that issue in a inline comment inside [`LanguageNegotiationContentEntity::processOutbound()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!language!src!Plugin!LanguageNegotiation!LanguageNegotiationContentEntity.php/function/LanguageNegotiationContentEntity%3A%3AprocessOutbound/).

At the moment, after applying the patch from that issue, query parameters get added to the URL as you would expect and without any need to instantiate 'prefix', but fragment doesn't. More work/comments should go into that issue to assist with resolving it.

As an alternative and in order to get fragments to work, you could try extending the Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator and replace the url_generator.non_bubbling service. (See https://www.drupal.org/node/2026959.)

---

Comment: Oh my... I actually read over that code, but did not check the issue assuming it was something specific for the language negotiation. Thanks for making me aware of this bug (I really thought I was doing something wrong). I'll leave the bounty open for a while to see if there are other options, but this has helped me a lot already. (The solution from `LanguageNegotiationContentEntity::processOutbound` where they simply rewrite the path seems reasonable.)

Comment: Good to know this helped. And yes, doing your own path processing there should be even simpler than the service override I suggested.

Comment: Apparently nobody knows another option. Bounty awarded, and thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed now for `$options['query']` on Drupal v8.5.5, but not yet for `$options['fragment']`. If someone needs to alter fragments in an OutboundPathProcessor, there is a core patch for fragments in this issue on d.o

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2881077#comment-12100638