# How to define caching for OutboundPathProcessor

Tags: 8, routes, caching

I've got a customized `OutboundPathProcesser` that adds GET parameters to URLs starting from a specific node type targetting a specific node id. Basically whenever I'm on a node of type product, I add the node id as GET Parameter to all URLs leading to my enquiry node.

A simplified version of my code is below.

```
public function processOutbound($path, &$options = array(), Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {

  $node = $request_stack->attributes->get('node');    
  if ($node->bundle() == 'product') {
    if ($path == $enquiryNodePath) {
      $options['query']['product_id'] = $node->id();
    }
  }
}
```

This mostly works, especially for enquiry links inside the full view of my products. But for enquiry links in menu blocks, the parameters are cached: When starting on a product page after cache clear, the GET parameters is appended on every page, when starting on a normal page, the GET parameters is never appended.

I greenly tried to add caching similar to [LanguageNegotiationUrl](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21language%21src%21Plugin%21LanguageNegotiation%21LanguageNegotiationUrl.php/function/LanguageNegotiationUrl%3A%3AprocessOutbound/8.2.x):

```
public function processOutbound($path, &$options = array(), Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {

  $node = $request_stack->attributes->get('node');    
  if ($node->bundle() == 'product') {
    if ($path == $enquiryNodePath) {
      if ($bubbleable_metadata) {
        $bubbleable_metadata
          ->addCacheContexts([
          'url.path',
        ]);
      }
      $options['query']['product_id'] = $node->id();
    }
  }
}
```

But this totally destroyed my site, it somehow corrupted the router table and even after disabling my module I was no longer able to [rebuild the router table](https://gist.github.com/mikecrittenden/837601592495b2b20df17d223d626812). I had to restore my site from a backup to fix the WSOD.

How do I correctly I make my OutboundPathProcessor / menu blocks cache-aware of the current node id?

(I do NOT want to disable caching for menu block with something like `max-age=0`)

Comment: What was the error message behind the WSOD?

Comment: `Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: INSERT INTO {router} (name, fit, path, pattern_outline, number_parts, route) VALUES ...` followed by a huge list of placeholders and values

Comment: Note: This was on my development server with no other users on the site, so the deadlock was not caused by normal site usage.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a problem adding that cache item would be likely to have caused...have you run through the same process again since restoring the database to confirm that one change was definitely to blame?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, it was a bit of trial & error, but this was the most significant code change before I got the error. The 2nd significant change was [applying the patch to make fragments work](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224227/outboundpathprocessor-is-not-appending-options-array/266365#266365), but I still have this patch applied right now and it seems to work

Comment: I agree with Clive that this error seems not to be connected. You definitely can add a cache context in a path processor. But it is not necessarily a good idea to cache menus and other page elements containing the link for each url (if cache size matters).

Comment: Where would you recommend adding the cache information instead? My 2nd idea was adding the path as cache context to all menu blocks, but I though doing it in OutboundPathProcessor (where I have the information if the link was modified and the cache needs to be set) was the clean way. The number of products is not that large, usually < 100

Comment: Yes, this is the clean way, this is why the path processor has the bubbleable metadata parameter. The problem is the amount of variations the context produces, not where you place it. You could use a custom cache context for the product id, so that you can be sure you only have < 100 variations.

Comment: I finally solved it with my own custom cache context based on `product_id ?: 0` as context value. One of my initial misunderstandings was conditionally adding the cache context inside the if-query. Adding the cache context outside with a default value was one part of the fix. The router error did not show up again, still don't know the cause for it.